# How to resolve "meteor isn't running a local mongo server" error?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am sure that I have a terminal to run the program and a terminal to run meteor Mongo but there will be still  an error:

```
"mongo: meteor isn't running a local mongo server."
```

Comment: Have you got meteor running before trying `meteor mongo`?

Comment: Do you use a local db started by Meteor?

Comment: I am very glad to someone answer my question.but
1. Using the local database is what mean?I am in the project to start the meteor mongo, should use is not local?
2. I'm sure I'm started the project and then run the meteor mongo oh, but it will still be an error.

Comment: Does the problem happen on developement (when you start with Meteor) or Is it happening in production(After a build).?